# Why can my cron job not find a specific command?

Tags: backup, centos, ftp, cron, duplicity

I am using duplicity to create nightly backups of my server over FTP.  I wrote a script that does both a local and remote backup and logs the output results.  When I run this script as the root user, it executes just fine.  However when I set it as a cron job and run it, the script executes but the ftp portion fails.  Shortly after I get an error message saying "ncftpls - command not found, please install ncftp 3.1.9 or later" but it is installed!  Is there some reason that cron job would not be able to find a command that exists on the machine?  Does it have it's own PATH or something like that?

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Mike

Comment: Is it root's cronttab?

Comment: Yes, it is root's script, root's crontab, and I compiled and installed ncftp as root.

Comment: Can you show the line from crontab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using absolute paths?  Cron jobs won't open an interactive shell, so bash init scripts (bashrc, bash_profile, etc.) that usually set the PATH may not be run--and if they are, they'll be using root's, not yours.  If you're unsure about where the command is, you can use `which <command>` to find out the absolute path.

When dealing with cron scripts, the general rule of thumb is, you either (a) want to set the PATH or (b) use absolute paths.

Good luck!

Comment: I recommend `type` over `which` because `type` also handles things like aliases. For example, in my shell, `which ls` responds with `/bin/ls`, but `type ls` responds with `ls is aliased to 'ls --color=auto -F'`

Answer (score 0):

You should either give the full path to the command you want to run or you should define `PATH` in the cron job.

Example of running the foobar command without giving a path:

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
01 * * * * root foobar
```

With a path:

```
01 * * * * root /usr/bin/foobar
```

You can also specify things like which shell to run the jobs in by setting `SHELL` like: `SHELL=/bin/bash` for bash. See `man 5 crontab` for some more examples.